# $http.get in angular to load external json

Tags: json, angularjs

Currently I have the following service which populates a table elsewhere in my angular app.

**Updated:**

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('projyApp')
      .service('data', function data() {
        // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function             

            var getAllPeeps = function () {
                return peeps;
            }

            var insertPeep = function(peep) {
                peeps.push(peep);
            }
            var getPeep = function(peep) {
                var foundPeep;
                if (peep.firstname) {
                    peeps.forEach(function (pps){
                        if (pps.firstname == peep.firstname) {
                            foundPeep = pps;
                        }
                    });
                } else if (peep.lastname) {
                    peeps.forEach(function (pps){
                        if (pps.lastname == peep.lastname) {
                            foundPeep = pps;
                        }
                    });
                } else if (peep.inumber) {
                    peeps.forEach(function (pps) {
                        if (pps.inumber == peep.tagid) {
                            foundPeep = pps;
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (foundPeep) {
                    return foundPeep;
                } else {
                    return "Error";
                }
            }

            var getDataFromServer = function () {
                //Fake it.
                var peeps = [
                    {firstname:'Buster', lastname:'Bluth', tagid:'01'},
                    {firstname:'John', lastname:'McClane', tagid:'02'},
                    {firstname:'Mister', lastname:'Spock', tagid:'03'}
                ];

                return peeps;
            }

            var peeps = getDataFromServer();

            return {
                getAllPeeps : getAllPeeps,
                insertPeep : insertPeep,
                getPeep : getPeep
            }
      });
```

Obviously this works, however I want the 'peeps' array to hold objects from an external json file.

How can I maintain functionality while loading the 'peeps' from an external json file like so:

```
$http.get("../../TestData/peeps.json").success(function(data) {

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular does 2 way binding from the get go. So if you have a

```
$scope.var = function() {
$http.get(blah).success($scope.peeps = data.peeps;);
};
```

It will update the $scope.peeps on your view. $scope.var being a button generally.

Comment: console is giving me "Error: Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- data"?

Comment: You have to inject $scope into your service.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I return the $http promise in angular. And the caller from the service can use success to do whatever it wants.
But to maintain backwards compability, you can try this:

```
var getDataFromServer = function () {
        var peeps = [];
        $http.get("../../TestData/peeps.json").success(function(data) {
             peeps.push.apply(peeps,data);
        });

        return peeps;
    }
```

So you'll return a initially empty array. But it'll be filled with the json array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myController($scope, $http){
    $http.get(url).success(function(data){ $scope.people = data; });
}
```